# Rihanna's accent in the song of "Diamonds"

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I like Rihanna and her song "[Diamonds](https://youtu.be/lWA2pjMjpBs?t=80)".

She sings the phrase "[At first sight I left the energy of sun rays](https://youtu.be/lWA2pjMjpBs?t=80)" at 01:25.
And I can't hear this "rays" but "ray-hey" or "ra-hey".

Is this her original accent or something? Or simple American emphasis?

Comment: Rihanna isn't American.  She's from Barbados.

Comment: Ever heard her song "Umbrella"? That has something similar to it.

Comment: @JB King Thank you for your information. I love the song "Umbrella" and listened to it frequently before. Please tell me what part of the song is similar.

Comment: @Daniel McLaury Sorry for my bad English. I didn't mean she is an American. But I didn't know she sings in Barbados English. Is "ray-hey" typical accent in Barbados English?

Comment: She speaks and sings with a definite Barbadian accent, though in this case what you're hearing is not an accent but just the way the song was written.  (That is, I agree with ssav)

Comment: After "Umbrella" in the song there is the "ella ella" part that is repeating part of a word that can either be seen as being part of the music or the language error as "ella" is just the last 2 syllables of the word rather than something new there.

Comment: @Daniel McLaury Very interesting. Please let me ask one more. Could you tell me what part of the song or any other her songs Rihanna sings with definite Barbadian accent? Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me @Daniel and the people who thought they should upvote your comment, but Barbados is in North America. Therefore she is indeed American.

Comment: @Octopus: Indeed, I know a lot of people who call themselves Americans and would take issue with the notion that "America" == USA. (Strangely, though this is common amongst my South American friends, Mexicans tend to not call themselves Americans).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Barbadian accent, Barbados, America, USA etc. very attracting my attention because they are important or kind of controversial.

Comment: But now, all I want to know is what part of the song or any other her songs Rihanna sings with definite Barbadian accent. Barbadian accent words, Barbadian way of singing or anything. Thank you.

Comment: Her song 'Man Down' sounds Barbadian to me (although being British I can't distinguish West Indian accents and dialects very well).  The way she pronounces 'pull the trigger' is quite distinctive.

Comment: @ssav Thank you for very useful information. You help me many times. This song "Man Down" is like reggae-ish, Jamaican-ish, so Bob Marley-ish. This is maybe Barbadian, I think. Anyway this moving and sad song made me love Rihanna more. Thank you again.

Comment: She sings 'pull the trigger', I hear it "pullin' togga".

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: I cannot find where the asker implies that Rihanna is American (despite Barbados being American. I know that you US guys like calling yourself Americans, but to os non-US-people, this sounds like calling Germany Europe, or Japan Asia, i.e. sometimes, it sounds strange)

Comment: @phrensel He asks about whether it's "American emphasis."  Rihanna doesn't speak like an American, she speaks like a Barbadian.  And concerning "American," it's literally the only demonym we have for ourselves.  There is no other word that means "person from the USA."  Other countries in North and South America have their own names and consequently their own demonyms; our country is just named after the continent.  And before you suggest we do something with the "United States" part, there's also a country in North America called "the United States of Mexico," so that's not doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just this singer's individual way of *singing* 'rays'. Since singing can be an emotional expression, coupled with a musical beat, as well as possible showmanship, singers will express words differently from how they do in *speech*. I'm sure it must be the same in your first language.

Your question reminds me about questions I had about words in a French song (or actually some French words in an American song). So I asked someone who spoke French. I found out that not every syllable corresponds to a word, because singers will add syllables to keep up with the beat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You learn French. It's the best advice from experienced learners like you.

Comment: That wasn't really advice, and I haven't learned French. I speak a couple other languages, and have studied even more. I find the French vowel sounds to be difficult. My native language is English.

Answer (score 31):

Neither.  It's music.

She wants to emphasize all three beats in the music, but because neither the word not the pitch changes, she adds in an extra consonant sound to distinguish the third beat from the second.

In speech, nobody says ray-heys when they mean rays.  (Just like nobody says umbrellaellaella when they mean umbrella!)  But if you listen to a lot of western pop music you'll find lots more examples.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Very helpful.

Comment: A-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-men.

Comment: Not to mention the chen-dury-ry from Sia's *Chandelier*

Comment: Ch-ch-ch-ch-changes.

Comment: I am still "ssad" about Bowie's recent death @ssav but the example with *[Changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAKuL8cyiAA)* is great!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes you are hearing her Bajan accent come out in that song. To prove it yourself, you can go to youtube and search for Bajan accent, Bajan Music etc. You'll get people from her Island, and you'll hear them sing the same way, but even more distinctly.

Having spent so much time in the USA has probably softened her original Bajan or Barbadian accent, and that's what you hear her sing with in that song.

If you read the linear notes on one of Rihanna's earlier CDs,Good Girl Gone Bad, you'll see people credited for Vocal Production.

This is something you usually don't see on any release for anyone. 
When she first started, people were hired to help her sound as American as possible, or to put it another way make her Bajan accent go away.

To that end, they coached her in the American R&B singing style that was foreign to her at the time, or to put it another way they taught her how to sound like a Black American when she sang.

That is not an insult by the way.

It's a compliment to the great success of Black American singers that someone coming from a place with its own strong Black singing traditions had to learn their way, before they can have their chance at success.

In Good Girl Gone Bad the vocal tricks of the trade that sounded so natural and smooth from Rihanna were the result of a lot of hard work and dedication both on her part and the vocal producers who worked on her songs with her.

Barbados may be a small Island, but it has a distinct culture and Barbadians speak their English dialect with a distinct accent.

Because Black music in the USA is so dominant, few people realize that it is just one of several musical styles, each distinct from each other that were a product of the African diaspora in the Americas.

Most are at least aware of Jamaican music, even if the don't listen to it, but far fewer are aware of the music of the smaller islands like Barbados which has mixed up all the various Black Caribbean styles and blended it with English traditional and pop music styles to create something of their own very distinct from Black American musical styles.

While she probably grew up listening to a fair share of American music, that doesn't mean she learned to sing that style perfectly.

That's why initially she needed the Vocal producers to help her sound perfect.

Obviously as she became a megastar the need for her to sound so American wasn't as important as it first was.

I wouldn't be surprised if she or one of her producers on that song decided it was a perfect opportunity to introduce elements of her natural singing style to see if it had any negative impact.

Obviously it didn't. So I imagine if another song comes along where her natural accent works with the song, I imagine they'll do it again.

And honestly she is such a big star now, she could sing practically any way she wanted, and as long as she hit the notes, she'd sell millions. Bitch bettah have my money is proof of that.

Comment: I've wached "Rihanna teaches us how to do a Bajan accent". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlEZNwWjcVA, and "SOME OLD BAJAN MUSIC Mixxx " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXA0mL2RfRI, but still I don't know. Please give me any examples of singing with Barbadian accent.